# Ajuda com responsividade e alinhamento

Tags: html, css

Estou fazendo um projeto pessoal e preciso de um empurrão. Eu me considero horrível no CSS e não tenho nenhuma habilidade nisso, então vim aqui para pedir ajuda.

O meu objetivo nisso é que as caixas de funções fiquem alinhadas (like an inline-block) mas caso não haja espaço para colocar mais uma, que as remanescentes consigam se adaptar ao espaço que eles tem para usar.

[image: Código da Aplicação]

Esse é o código CSS que eu estou usando no momento:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

body {
    background: url('./assets/bg.jpg');
}

.main-container {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    flex: 1;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgb(9, 72, 240);
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px black;
}

.actionBox {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    max-width: 450px;
    max-height: 500px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px black;
}

.actionDescription {
    color: gray;
}

.actionHrline {
    color: gray;
    border: 1 0;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}

.btnOk {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: rgb(9, 72, 240);
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid rgb(9, 72, 240);
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btnOk:hover {
    color: white;
    background: rgb(9, 72, 240);
}
```

E essa é a construção das divs no HTML.

```html
<div class="main-container">
            <div class="navbar">
                <h2>Home Helper</h2>
            </div>
            ´
            <div class="actionBox">
                <h3>Tomar café</h3>
                <p class="actionDescription">Algo aqui.</p>
                <hr class="actionHrline">

                <h4>Deseja ligar a cafeteira com o Arduino?</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btnOk"><h3>Ligar</h3></button>
            </div>

            <div class="actionBox">
                <h3>Ativar Aplicações</h3>
                <p class="actionDescription">Algo aqui.</p>
                <hr class="actionHrline">

                <h4>Deseja acessar o Appanel?</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btnOk"><h3>Ligar</h3></button>
            </div>

            <div class="actionBox">
                <h3>Gerenciar senhas</h3>
                <p class="actionDescription">Algo aqui.</p>
                <hr class="actionHrline">

                <h4>Deseja ler o Extrato?</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btnOk"><h3>Ligar</h3></button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Qual sua dúvida? O que você quer que aconteça?

Comment: Acabei de editar o post, esqueci de escrever o mais importante. XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar [Flex Container](https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/). Alterei seu código, onde eu criei uma **div** com ***id="conteudo"*** apliquei nela `display: flex;` e `flex-wrap: wrap;`. Também alterei sua classe ***.actionBox*** acrescentando `min-width: 300px;`. Segue o código:

### CSS

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

body {
    background: url('./assets/bg.jpg');
}

.main-container {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    flex: 1;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgb(9, 72, 240);
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px black;
}

.actionBox {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    max-width: 450px;
    max-height: 500px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px black;
    min-width: 300px;
}

.actionDescription {
    color: gray;
}

#conteudo{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

### HTML

```
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="navbar">
            <h2>Home Helper</h2>
        </div>
            
        <div id="conteudo">
        
            <div class="actionBox">
                <h3>Tomar café</h3>
                <p class="actionDescription">Algo aqui.</p>
                <hr class="actionHrline">

                <h4>Deseja ligar a cafeteira com o Arduino?</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btnOk"><h3>Ligar</h3></button>
            </div>

            <div class="actionBox">
                <h3>Ativar Aplicações</h3>
                <p class="actionDescription">Algo aqui.</p>
                <hr class="actionHrline">

                <h4>Deseja acessar o Appanel?</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btnOk"><h3>Ligar</h3></button>
            </div>

            <div class="actionBox">
                <h3>Gerenciar senhas</h3>
                <p class="actionDescription">Algo aqui.</p>
                <hr class="actionHrline">

                <h4>Deseja ler o Extrato?</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btnOk"><h3>Ligar</h3></button>
            </div>
            <div class="actionBox">
                <h3>Gerenciar senhas</h3>
                <p class="actionDescription">Algo aqui.</p>
                <hr class="actionHrline">

                <h4>Deseja ler o Extrato?</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btnOk"><h3>Ligar</h3></button>
            </div>
            <div class="actionBox">
                <h3>Gerenciar senhas</h3>
                <p class="actionDescription">Algo aqui.</p>
                <hr class="actionHrline">

                <h4>Deseja ler o Extrato?</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btnOk"><h3>Ligar</h3></button>
            </div>
            <div class="actionBox">
                <h3>Gerenciar senhas</h3>
                <p class="actionDescription">Algo aqui.</p>
                <hr class="actionHrline">

                <h4>Deseja ler o Extrato?</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btnOk"><h3>Ligar</h3></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta adicionar um `float: left` nos boxes (classe `.actionBox`) que eles ficaram alinhados um ao lado do outro. Como você só colocou `max-width` na classe, os boxes ficarão com a largura do conteúdo, portanto, um poderá ser maior que o outro, mas nunca maior que `450px` colocado no `max-width`.

Veja:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

body {
    background: url('./assets/bg.jpg');
}

.main-container {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    flex: 1;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgb(9, 72, 240);
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px black;
}

.actionBox {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    max-width: 450px;
    max-height: 500px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px black;
    float: left;
}

.actionDescription {
    color: gray;
}

.actionHrline {
    color: gray;
    border: 1 0;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}

.btnOk {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: rgb(9, 72, 240);
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid rgb(9, 72, 240);
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btnOk:hover {
    color: white;
    background: rgb(9, 72, 240);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
   <div class="navbar">
       <h2>Home Helper</h2>
   </div>
   ´
   <div class="actionBox">
       <h3>Tomar café</h3>
       <p class="actionDescription">Algo aqui.</p>
       <hr class="actionHrline">

       <h4>Deseja ligar a cafeteira com o Arduino?</h4>
       <button type="button" class="btnOk"><h3>Ligar</h3></button>
   </div>

   <div class="actionBox">
       <h3>Ativar Aplicações</h3>
       <p class="actionDescription">Algo aqui.</p>
       <hr class="actionHrline">

       <h4>Deseja acessar o Appanel?</h4>
       <button type="button" class="btnOk"><h3>Ligar</h3></button>
   </div>

   <div class="actionBox">
       <h3>Gerenciar senhas</h3>
       <p class="actionDescription">Algo aqui.</p>
       <hr class="actionHrline">

       <h4>Deseja ler o Extrato?</h4>
       <button type="button" class="btnOk"><h3>Ligar</h3></button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicione `float:left;` na sua classe `.actionBox`.

Isso deve resolver seu problema

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite,

você pode usar o flex box
basta usar na div pai as propriedades

```
***DISPLAY : FLEX;
flex-wrap: wrap;***
```

(caso a tela nao caiba lado a lado ela vai uma em baixo da outra automaticamente)